# Yeardropdown in reactdatepicker month picker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using https://reactdatepicker.com/ like this using the showMonthYearPicker property:
[image]

Does anyone know how to turn the yearselector into a dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

The prop you are looking for is `showYearDropdown`

Source: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-year-dropdown

Comment: Thx for replying. I tried it but it with this combination of properties: showYearDropdown
dropdownMode="select"
showMonthYearPicker
dateFormat="MM/yyyy" and the dropdown does not appear.